# web api with connection to mongodb doesn't return proper json

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I try to create a web api and in one action for testing purposes I try to connect to mongodb database and return as a result json(as I want to be abel to use this Webapi not only from .net client but also from html page for example)

```
public class Default1Controller : ApiController
    {
        public IMongoCollection<Category> Get()
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient();

            var db = client.GetDatabase("local");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<Category>("category");
            List<Category> model = (from contact in collection
                                    select new Category
                    {
                        id = contact["_id"].AsString,
                        name = contact["name"].AsString,
                        datecreated = contact["String"].AsString
                    }).ToList();
            return collection;
        }
```

and I get strange output and I can't figure out why I don't get the proper results:

```
$id":"1","CollectionNamespace":{"$id":"2","CollectionName":"category","DatabaseNamespace":{"$id":"3","DatabaseName":"local"},"FullName":"local.category"},"Database":{"$id":"4","Client":{"$id":"5","Cluster":{"$id":"6","ClusterId":{"$id":"7","_value":1},"Description":{"$id":"8","ClusterId":{"$ref":"7"},"Servers":[{"$id":"9","AverageRoundTripTime":"00:00:00.0040000","CanonicalEndPoint":null,"ElectionId":null,"EndPoint":{"$id":"10","Host":"localhost","AddressFamily":0,"Port":27017},"HeartbeatException":null,"MaxBatchCount":1000,"MaxDocumentSize":16777216,"MaxMessageSize":48000000,"MaxWireDocumentSize":4210688,"ReplicaSetConfig":null,"ServerId":{"$id":"11","_clusterId":{"$id":"7","_value":1},"_endPoint":["DnsEndPoint","localhost",27017,0]},"State":1,"Tags":null,"Type":1,"Version":{"$id":"12","Major":3,"Minor":0,"Patch":3,"PreRelease":null},"WireVersionRange":{"$id":"13","Max":3,"Min":0}}],"State":1,"Type":1},"Settings":{"$id":"14","ConnectionMode":0,"EndPoints":[{"$ref":"10"}],"MaxServerSelectionWaitQueueSize":500,"ReplicaSetName":null,"ServerSelectionTimeout":"00:00:30","PreServerSelector":null,"PostServerSelector":{"$id":"15"}}},"Settings":{"$id":"16","ClusterConfigurator":null,"ConnectionMode":0,"ConnectTimeout":"00:00:30","Credentials":[],"GuidRepresentation":2,"IsFrozen":true,"IPv6":false,"LocalThreshold":"00:00:00.0150000","MaxConnectionIdleTime":"00:10:00","MaxConnectionLifeTime":"00:30:00","MaxConnectionPoolSize":100,"MinConnectionPoolSize":0,"ReadEncoding":null,"ReadPreference":{"$id":"17","ReadPreferenceMode":0,"TagSets":[]},"ReplicaSetName":null,"Server":{"$id":"18","_host":"localhost","_port":27017},"Servers":[{"$ref":"18"}],"SocketTimeout":"00:00:00","SslSettings":null,"UseSsl":false,"VerifySslCertificate":true,"WaitQueueSize":500,"WaitQueueTimeout":"00:02:00","WriteConcern":{"$id":"19","FSync":null,"IsAcknowledged":true,"Journal":null,"W":null,"WTimeout":null},"WriteEncoding":null}},"DatabaseNamespace":{"$ref":"3"},"Settings":{"$id":"20","GuidRepresentation":2,"IsFrozen":true,"ReadEncoding":null,"ReadPreference":{"$ref":"17"},"SerializerRegistry":{"$id":"21"},"WriteConcern":{"$ref":"19"},"WriteEncoding":null}},"DocumentSerializer":{"$id":"22","IsDiscriminatorCompatibleWithObjectSerializer":true,"ValueType":"MvcApplication1.Controllers.Category, MvcApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"},"Indexes":{"$id":"23","CollectionNamespace":{"$ref":"2"},"DocumentSerializer":{"$ref":"22"},"Settings":{"$id":"24","AssignIdOnInsert":true,"GuidRepresentation":2,"IsFrozen":true,"ReadEncoding":null,"ReadPreference":{"$ref":"17"},"SerializerRegistry":{"$ref":"21"},"WriteConcern":{"$ref":"19"},"WriteEncoding":null}},"Settings":{"$ref":"24"}}
```

Comment: You didn't say what you are trying to get back, but it looks to me like your Get() method ought to be returning model, not collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the old synchronous driver then you need to call the **`FindAll()`** method. Because you are using WebApi Controller, simply return the enumerable collection of data returned from the **`FindAll()`** method. The returned Enumerable is then converted into a List of Category objects:

```
public class Default1Controller : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Get()
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("local");
        List<Category> model = new List<Category>();
        var categoryList = db.GetCollection<Category>("category").FindAll().AsEnumerable();
        model = (from category in contactsList
                    select new Category
                    {
                        id = category["_id"].AsString,
                        name = category["name"].AsString,
                        datecreated = category["String"].AsString
                    }
                ).ToList();
        return model;            
    }
}
```

Comment: No i don't have FindAll method available. It seems I'm using the new driver and actually there is no method that can return me something as Enumerable